# Spring Expression error when displaying details in form using thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to display user data after joining two tables on a view using thymeleaf template html file. My repository query annotation is

```
@Query("SELECT u.username,p.privi_name FROM Users u inner join u.priviJoin p")
List<Users> findByUsername();
```

And my controller is ,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/joinResult", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView joinResultShow(Model model)
    {
        List<Users> use = new ArrayList<Users>(); 
        use = (List<Users>) userRepo.findByUsername();
        model.addAttribute("joinData",use);
        ModelAndView viewObj = new ModelAndView("fleethome");
        return viewObj;
    }
```

And my html file fleethome is,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <body>
    <div>          
      <span th:text="${joinData.username}">
      </span>
      <span th:text="${joinData.privi_name}">
      </span>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

My Users class is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "username")
public String username;

@Column(name = "password")
public String password;

@Column(name = "privid")
public Integer privid;

@OneToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="join_privillage")
private Privillages priviJoin;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public Integer getPrivid() {
    return privid;
}

public void setPrivid(Integer privid) {
    this.privid = privid;
}

public Privillages getPriviJoin() {
    return priviJoin;
}

public void setPriviJoin(Privillages priviJoin) {
    this.priviJoin = priviJoin;
}



public Users() {
}

public Users(String username, String password, Integer privid) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.privid = privid;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Users[id=%d, username='%s', password='%s']", id, 
username, password);
}

}
```

And My second joining class Privillages is,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "privillages")
public class Privillages implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public  Integer id;

@Column(name = "privid")
public Integer privid;

@Column(name = "privi_name")
public String privi_name;

@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="priviJoin")
public Users user;


public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Integer getPrivid() {
    return privid;
}

public void setPrivid(Integer privid) {
    this.privid = privid;
}

public String getPrivi_name() {
    return privi_name;
}

public void setPrivi_name(String privi_name) {
    this.privi_name = privi_name;
}

public Users getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(Users user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public Privillages() {
}

public Privillages(Integer privid, String privi_name ) {
    this.privid = privid;
    this.privi_name = privi_name;

}
}
```

And displaying error like "There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "joinData.username" (fleethome:54)".What I need to do to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model attribute is type of List.So you should use **th:each** in your template to iterate the list of users: You can try this :

```
<div th:each= "user: ${joinData}">
   <span th:text="${user.username}">
      </span>
      <span th:text="${user.privi_name}">
      </span>
</div>
```

**Solution :**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Users u ")
List<Users> findByUsername();
```

**And Display like :**

```
 <div th:each= "user: ${joinData}">
       <span th:text="${user.username}">
          </span>
          <span th:text="${user.priviJoin.privi_name}">
          </span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Now there is no error. But displaying null for data. Is there any mistake i did in my repository join query?

Comment: Can you add your **Users** and **PriviJoin**  classes   in your question detail.